# Unable to serialize to JSON. Unrecognized type Eagertensor when using ModelCheckpoint callback and validation data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to replicate the [Keras example of Vision Transformers with small datasets](https://keras.io/examples/vision/vit_small_ds/). The differences between my code and the original code is that I added and called a callback in training and I also have validation data. The callback and its call are described below.

```
cbs = [ModelCheckpoint("ViT-Model-new-small-dataset.h5", save_best_only=True), EarlyStopping(patience=50, monitor='val_Accuracy', mode='max' ,restore_best_weights=True)]

history = model.fit(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=cbs
)
```

However, whenever I run such I code I have the following error after the first training epoch:

```
 File "vit_test_small_datasets.py", line 359, in <module>
    history = run_experiment(vit_sl)
  File "vit_test_small_datasets.py", line 335, in run_experiment
    history = model.fit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: Unable to serialize [  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53
  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125
 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143] to JSON. Unrecognized type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>.
```

**What I tried:**
There is a discussion [here](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/using-efficientnetb0-and-save-model-will-result-unable-to-serialize-2-0896919-2-1128857-2-1081853-to-json-unrecognized-type-class-tensorflow-python-framework-ops-eagertensor/12518) saying that it must be a tensorflow bug and with tf 2.9.1 or 2.9.0 it can work. However in my case the error persists even after dowgrading the tensorflow version to those described.

**Edit:** I realized that the error happens when the validation accuracy is calculated. If I run model.fit without validation_data=(x_valid,y_valid) and without ModelCheckpoint the error is not happening.

Is that possible to run the [Keras example of Vision Transformers with small datasets](https://keras.io/examples/vision/vit_small_ds/) source code with a callback like I showed above?

Comment: In callback, you set ` monitor='val_Accuracy'`, but it should be ` monitor='val_accuracy'`. This monitoring name should be matched with a training log. I tried your code in TF 2.12, it works just fine.

Comment: @Innat thank you so much for your answer. I am using TF 2.11 and still have the same error even with your changes proposed. Is this a TF version related error?